# sample C++ project Warning in compile

Tags: c++

i have a sample C++ code - So that give me a Warning with this content : 
[Warning] extended initializer lists only available with -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11
how i can solve that ?

This is my code :

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
struct CandyBar
{
 const  char Brand[255];
  float Weight;
  int Calories;
};
  CandyBar Snake{"Mocha Munch",2.3,350};

int main()
{
  cout << Snake.Brand << endl;
  cout << Snake.Weight << endl;
  cout << Snake.Calories << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: its telling you exactly what to pass to the compiler.

Comment: side note: Use `std::string` instead.

Comment: This doesn’t address the question, but do you really need the extra stuff that `std::endl` does? `’\n’` ends a line.

Comment: @PeteBecker Not solved

Comment: @SombreroChicken not solved

Comment: @NeilButterworth Can you Explain how i should change in codes ?

Comment: So many answers in comments. Sigh. Is a _question & answer_ site really that difficult to use?

Comment: For me I usually worry if the question is too trivial or whether it has a duplicate. I expect this question has dozens of duplicates.

Comment: @drescherjm Neither of which is an excuse to callously bypass the peer review system, as you know

Answer (score 2):

The error message tells you what to do.

You're trying to use a C++11 feature, so enable C++11 mode by passing `-std=c++11` to your compiler. If you're using some build system instead of just calling `g++` on the command-line, read its documentation to find out how to achieve this.

Or you could upgrade your compiler, because C++11 or even C++14 is the default in more up-to-date versions.